Patent Act in Europe
I get few feedback from Europe examiners, and I made a mistake that I used accordance with the requirement of 35 USC 112
anyone knows there is similar act or regulations in Europe Patent Law.

I’m not sure what you are asking. Can you elaborate ?

@cmabill It would help a lot if you could edit the actual question adding as much detail as you can. Even with your comment I am not sure what you are asking.

You might be referring to U.S. practice there often including a statement that embodiments are examples and the claims define the invention. There is no law requiring that statement.
It is settled that the claims define the invention. To understand the claims you use the ordinary meaning of words unless they are established to have special meanings in the context of the specification. Also you read the claims “in light of the specification” but it is improper to “import limitations” from the specification into the claims. This can be a fine line.
Judges are known to decide that what the inventor “invented”  is something narrower that the plain words of the claim by taking aspects from the specification as limiting the claims. In my opinion this is not according to the law, but judges sometimes do it. So practitioners need to be very careful in the wording of everything. That’s why those statements appear in U.S. patents.
Claiming and examining are different in the EPO. The U.S. uses peripheral claiming meaning the words draw a boundary between what is claimed and what isn’t claimed. In the EPO they use central claiming. The claim defines the core of the invention.
The issues of embodiment only being an example are still present but thought of differently. When I filed patents overseas  for my U.S. clients I relied on advise from practitioners in those jurisdictions.
Also examination is very different. In the EPO the examiner first fines the closest prior art and, if the claims are novel over it, considers inventive step. What step is needed to go from the identified closest prior art to the claimed invention. It depends heavily on the examiner’s chosen closest prior art.
If you invent the windsurfer is the closest prior art a small sailboat or a surf board ? The analysis is different.

I’m sorry but if the posters here have trouble understanding your questions it seems unlikely you can reach a positive result with examiners on your own. Good luck.

Thank you, George always.
